# how to get result size for every select query ran using criteria and specification in springs?

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, hibernate-criteria

In JAVA after execution of the query I am counting the result set size in common database utils file before returning the data to monitor queries which are selecting more than 1000 rows. I would like to do the same in springs for both criteria and specification queries. How to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

Logic I am following in java while executing query to send mail when there is a query extracting more than 2500 results.

```
Vector result = new Vector();
Vector row;
int colIndex;
int rowCount = 0;
int colCount;
ResultSet rst = null;
try {
 rst = executeQuery(xQuery);
 colCount = rst.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
 while (rst.next()) {
  row = new Vector();
  for (colIndex = 1; colIndex <= colCount; colIndex++) {
   if (rst.getString(colIndex) != null && rst.getString(colIndex) != "")
    row.add(colIndex - 1, rst.getString(colIndex));
   else
    row.add(colIndex - 1, " ");
  }
  result.add(rowCount++, row);
 }
 try {
  if (result.size() > 2500) {

   Mailer(dbConn.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL(), xQuery, result.size());
  }
 } catch (Exception e) {

 }

} catch (Exception e) {
 throw e;
} finally {
 if (rst != null) rst.close();
 rst = null;
}
return result;
```

Comment: Can you show at least something you have done?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, you need to be able to use Hibernate Criteria to determine if the `Resultset` returned has more than 2500 rows. This can be achieved by obtaining a list from the `Criteria` and then determining the size of the List. For example, say you are querying a purchase Orders table:

```
public static List<PurchaseOrders> getPurchaseOrderDetails() {
        List<PurchaseOrders> orders = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(PurchaseOrders.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("delFlg", "N"));
            ////add whatever other filters here
            orders = cr.list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return orders;
    }
```

This is an equivalent of :

```
select * from purchase_orders where del_flg = 'N';
```

Note that `PurchaseOrders` is your `jpa` class having the database object mapping. Since you already have a List from here, you can always check the size.

```
public static void sendAlert() {
        List<PurchaseOrders> orders = getPurchaseOrderDetails();
        int size = orders.size();
        if(size > 2500){
            ///Initiate alerts
        }
    }
```

### Update

If you need to cover all your queries in one method, you will need to write a generic method:

```
public static <T> List<T> getDetails(Class<T> c, Map<String, ?> params) {
        List<T> details = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(c);
            params.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
                cr.add(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
            });
            details = cr.list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return details;
    }
```

and then fill in the parameters for your different queries and tables.

Comment: This will work but I have to do code changes at many places. Instead I can have the logic some place, which executes for all queries. Can we achieve this in hibernate layer or somewhere ?

Comment: In this case you will need a generic Method to cover all your query cases. See the update In the answer.